# How to generate documentation for existing angularjs site using swagger

Tags: angularjs, documentation, swagger

I am working on existing site made in `angular.js` which consumes some REST API.
Is there a way to generate `swagger` documentation, at least some skeleton, starting from existing site, from client perspective?
I want to avoid writing documentation from begging. It would be nice to generate some starting point documentation based on existing code and then refine it.

Is it possible?

Comment: I don't really see how Swagger and Angular relate - isn't Swagger mainly for documenting REST APIs?

Comment: Yes. My angular app consumes REST API so is there a way to generate some API from consumer perspective or I need server side code to be able to generate some API docs?

Comment: Ah, I get what you mean now. No, Swagger is run on the server side, either through code annotations or by defining a schema. As far as I know, there's no way to automatically generate it from the client side, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks. Can you post your comment as answer in order to accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, Swagger cannot be used from the client-side to automatically generate documentation. You either have to add code annotations on the server-side, or create a schema manually using something like http://editor.swagger.io.